# C++ function overload cause seg fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have struct called Set.

```
struct Set {
string name;
string value;
bool is_condition;
bool is_bool_val; };
```

I have to store many of these 'Set' structures, so I am using a vector.

```
vector<Set> list;
```

For context, I am storing data about a mobile device such as an iPhone. A list of Set's describes one device! For example, an instance of set could have the following...

```
Set phone;
phone.name = "Serial Number";
phone.value = "FLMJ0000GGGG";
phone.is_condition = false;
phone.is_bool = false;
```

is_condition, tells me that this instance of Set needs to store either 'Good' or 'Bad' as the value. is_bool, tells me that the instance of Set needs to store a boolean value. See the below example.

```
Set device_wiped;
device_wiped.name = "Device Wiped";
device_wiped.is_bool = true;
```

Extrapolating from is_bool allows me to get input of either true or false, meaning the device either has, or has not been wiped (restored to factory settings).

I am using an overloaded wrapper function called new_set to create my Set elements, which are stored in my 'list' vector.

```
Set new_set(string name, const bool is_bool, const bool is_condition) {
    Set set;
    set.name = name;
    set.is_bool = is_bool;
    set.is_condition = is_condition;
    return set;
}

Set new_set(string name, const bool is_bool) {
    return new_set(name, is_bool);
}

Set new_set(string name) {
    return new_set(name, false, false);
}
```

I have three wrapper functions as this makes it easier to implement (I only want to write parameters if I have to!). This compiles fine, but I can not run. Crashes on a segmentation fault. Let me know if you need the entire code.

For now I am not needing to store data in the Set.value or Set.condition fields. I just want to initialise them all with a name the booleans.

Comment: there is `std::set`, so if somewhere you said `using namespace std;` then there will be compilation errors. Also how you initialize variables in `new_set` does not make much sense.

Comment: There's no way to know what your error is from what you've posted.  You need to reduce your code down to a [mcve].  Chances are you'll find your error in the process of doing so, but if you don't then people here will be able to help you.

Comment: By the way, `if(b) s.b = true; else s.b = false;` can be simplified to just `s.b = b;`

Comment: I am using the std namespace sorry. And also I am doing this:

list.push_back(new_set("Serial Number"));

@macroland

Comment: @MilesBudnek There is, I did reduce it and attempt to fix before posting.

Comment: This `new_set` function seems like it would be better suited as a constructor of the `Set` class.

Comment: @SirGuy very true!! I feel so dumb, make me a coffee pls haha

Comment: @SirGuy I agree, but it is for a procedural programming assignment. No OOP. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the second function:

```
Set new_set(string name, const bool is_bool) {
    return new_set(name, is_bool);
}
```

There's an endless recursion here. I guess you meant `return new_set(name, is_bool, false);` or `return new_set(name, is_bool, true);`.

By the way, your three functions can be simplified into one as follow (as @SirGuy mentioned):

```
Set new_set(string name, const bool is_bool = false, const bool is_condition = false) {
    Set set;
    set.name = name;
    set.is_bool_val = is_bool;
    set.is_condition = is_condition;
    return set;
}
```

Comment: Also `Set new_set(string name, bool is_bool = false, bool is_condition = false){...}` in this case circumvents the overloads entirely.

Comment: @SirGuy Not sure I follow this, can you give me a resource or the name of this so I can look it up.

Comment: @Dan Search for `Default arguments C++`